# Solr Query doesn't work in one dc but works in other dc

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

We have tried query which is fetching record from one data center but not in other. I checked /etc/dse/default file and can see solr_enabled = 1 on both the dc nodes. Could you tell me what else i need to check to fix this issue. Also I am unable to find solrconfig.xml and schema.xml for solr. Where can i find these to compare. Thank you very much.

Comment: solrconfig.xml and schema.xml are stored in the database. You can try going to http://<localhost>:8983/solr/#/, use the core selector, and browsing the schema. Replace localhost with the ip address of one of your solr nodes. Or just grab the files `http://localhost:8983/solr/resource/keyspace.tablename/solrconfig.xml` where you replace keyspace.tablename with your own solr-indexed table.

Comment: You might also want to use the CQL DESCRIBE command from cqlsh and post the keyspace information and schema from the table that backs your Solr core.